# Como converter todas as letras maiúsculas em minúsculas com sed

Tags: regex, bash, shell-script, shell

Estou tentando converter todas as letras minúsculas com `sed`:

```bsh
repository="https://github.com/facebook/React.git"
repo=`echo  "$repository"  | sed -n -e 's/^.*\/\([^.]*\)\(.git\)*/\1/p'`
echo $repo
```

Tentei desta forma mas não deu certo:

```bsh
repository="https://github.com/facebook/React.git"
repo=`echo  "$repository"  | sed -n -e 's/.*/\L&/^.*\/\([^.]*\)\(.git\)*/\1/p'`
echo $repo
```

Minha intenção é que saia o nome do repositório apenas em minúsculo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você quase acertou, bastava colocar um `\L` antes do `\1`:

```bsh
repo=`echo  "$repository"  | sed -n -e 's/^.*\/\([^.]*\)\(.git\)*/\L\1/p'`
                                                                  ^^
                                                                  aqui
```

Com isso, o conteúdo do grupo 1 (que no caso é o nome do repositório) é convertido para minúsculo.

Na verdade dá para encurtar a expressão, pois você coloca `\(.git\)*`, o que significa que `.git` pode se repetir zero ou mais vezes (ou seja, poderia não ter o `.git` no final, ou terminar com `.git.git.git`). Para ser mais preciso, poderia mudar para:

```bsh
repo=`echo  "$repository"  | sed -n -e 's/^.*\/\([^.]*\)\.git$/\L\1/p'`
```

Desta forma, eu garanto que deve terminar com `.git` (pois incluí o [marcador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `$`, que indica o final da string), e este só pode ocorrer exatamente uma vez.

---

Só para constar, existem outras alternativas, com `tr` e `awk`:

```bsh
repo=`echo  "$repository"  | sed -n -e 's/^.*\/\([^.]*\)\.git$/\1/p'| tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`
```

```bsh
repo=`echo  "$repository"  | sed -n -e 's/^.*\/\([^.]*\)\.git$/\1/p'| awk '{print tolower($0)}'`
```

Ou ainda, você pode continuar deixando a variável `$repo` com o valor em maiúsculas, e somente converter na hora de imprimir:

```bsh
# repo é "React"
repo=`echo  "$repository"  | sed -n -e 's/^.*\/\([^.]*\)\.git$/\1/p'`
# mas ao imprimir assim, é mostrado "react"
echo ${repo,,}
```

A explicação do código acima está [aqui](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/260721).
Claro que você também poderia fazer assim, caso queira que a variável tenha o valor em minúsculo:

```bsh
repo=`echo ${repo,,}`
```

Answer (score 2):

Achei essa solução no [stackoverflow em inglês para um toLower em bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2264537/2405914)

```
$ echo "$a" | sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\L\1/'
hi all
# isso também funciona:
$ sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\L\1/' <<< "$a"
hi all
```

Basicamente, converteria todas as letras da entrada para minúsculo.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode desabilitar o atributo *upper-case* da variável com `declare -l NOME_VARIAVEL`. Assim, quando a variável recebe um valor, todos os caracteres maiúsculos são convertidos em minúsculos.

No seu caso, apenas use

```bash
declare -l repository="https://github.com/facebook/React.git"
```

De forma similar, pode usar `declare -u NOME_VARIAVEL` para converter a maiúsculas.

Para mais detalhes consulte o manual: `man declare`